# Highligth in a div using Dart

Tags: regex, dart

I have a div tag.

The innter html could look like this.

<span class="a class">test and</span>

Now Id like a regualar expression which can find the n in 'and' but not find the n in the span tags.

I need a regular expression I can find content with but never something inside html tags.

It has to work in dart =)
Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get the content of your html element with `innerHtml` and run your regular expression on that content.